# Report Generation through Screenshots from a SPA Web Application - Design choices & options

Tags: javascript, reporting, puppeteer, headless-browser

**Requirement**:

For multiple screens and actions on my SPA website (behind authentication), I need to take screenshots. The ultimate aim is to export the images to a Powerpoint Presentation.

The screenshots are to be taken for multiple scenarios like:

1. On clicking a button which zooms another element on screen (without page refresh)
2. Selecting options on screens and then taking screenshot

**Options Explored**:

1. Use a tool like Chrome Puppeteer or Selenium or Cypress, and render the website in a headless way in backend and take screenshots.

**Question**:

1. Is there a way this could be achieved in front end in JavaScript?
2. Can a browser launch another headless browser?
3. Are there better design options?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using a Javascript library ([html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) for example)
The disadvantage is cross browser support (there is no guarantee it will look the same on all browsers)
So use it only if you are rendering simple HTML/CSS elements

A small server running Puppeteer is the best option IMO

Comment: Thanks.  But as mentioned in my Requirements section, the reports are to be generated with interactivity.  As in user needs report of a particular state of the screen which materializes after a set of actions & JS rules.  Won't doing it in front end cause confusion to user? Like screen automatically pressing buttons etc.

Comment: I am not sure I understand that requirement, you can also use this library for hidden elements I assume.